# Is there any endless mode in Super Hexagon?

Tags: super-hexagon

I've unlocked Hexagon, Hexagoner, Hexagonest, Hexagon (Hyper), Hexagoner (Hyper) but not Hexagonest (Hyper) so is there any hidden endless level to be unlocked after I complete them all or Super Hexagon doesn't have any endless mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 6 distinct levels in Super Hexagon (those that you've listed.) There is no hidden endless mode beyond this.

The sixth level, Hyper Hexagonest, has an implicit end - once you beat 60 seconds, you'll get to see something nice. All other levels are effectively endless already - i.e. you can theoretically continue playing until you hit a wall (either within the game, or in the real world out of frustration.)

[(Source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Hexagon)

Answer (score 0):

Every level is endless.

There are only 6 levels, nothing else.

Comment: No it isn't, say if you are playing hexagon level then after 60 seconds, the level switches to hyper hexagon

Comment: So? It's still endless. But no, there's no hidden levels or the sort.